# How to do Nested SUM in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have three tables `invoice_lineItem`, `contract_Details` and `Tranche`.

What I want to achieve is to get total purchase price of contracts based on `contractID` from `invoice_lineItem` and `contract_Details` and then get `TotalPurchasePrice` of all contract in the same tranche.

Here's the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67123/1 of what I've tried

> I get purchase price of contractID of other tranche added to
>   trancheID 1 as shown below

```
create table invoice_lineItem(
   inv_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   contractID VARCHAR(255),
   purchasePrice INT,
   PRIMARY KEY(inv_id)
);

create table contract_details(
   contractID VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL,
   funder VARCHAR(255),
   PRIMARY KEY(contractID)
);

create table tranche_details(
   contractID  VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL,
   trancheID VARCHAR(255),
   PRIMARY KEY(contractID)
);

insert into invoice_lineItem(contractID,purchasePrice) VALUES ('1/14S/03',5);
insert into invoice_lineItem(contractID,purchasePrice) VALUES ('1/14S/03',5);
insert into invoice_lineItem(contractID,purchasePrice) VALUES ('2/14S/03',15);
insert into invoice_lineItem(contractID,purchasePrice) VALUES ('2/14S/03',15);
insert into invoice_lineItem(contractID,purchasePrice) VALUES ('3/14S/03',5);

insert into contract_details(contractID,funder) VALUES ('1/14S/03','ABC');
insert into contract_details(contractID,funder) VALUES ('2/14S/03','ABC');
insert into contract_details(contractID,funder) VALUES ('3/14S/03','ABC');

insert into tranche_details(contractID,trancheID) VALUES ('1/14S/03',1);
insert into tranche_details(contractID,trancheID) VALUES ('2/14S/03',1);
insert into tranche_details(contractID,trancheID) VALUES ('3/14S/03',2);


SELECT cd.contractID,SUM(inv.purchasePrice) as totalPP
FROM `contract_details` cd INNER JOIN invoice_lineitem inv ON inv.contractID=cd.contractID 
WHERE cd.funder='ABC'
```

What i want to achieve is to get

> totalPurchasePrice For All Contracts with same contractID and the
>   funder Name 'ABC' from ContractDetails

```
inv_id:1
contractID:1/14S/03
PurchasePrice:5 

inv_id:2
contractID:1/14S/03
PurchasePrice:5
```

So total PurchasePrice is: 10 and similarly for 2/14S/03 it will be 30 and  now since contractID:1/14S/03 and contractID:2/14S/03 are in same tranche I want to SUM their totalPurchase Price

```
SELECT cd.contractID,SUM(inv.purchasePrice) as totalPP FROM `contract_details` cd 
INNER JOIN invoice_lineitem inv ON inv.contractID=cd.contractID
INNER JOIN tranche_details td ON td.trancheID=(SELECT trancheID FROM tranche_details GROUP by trancheID having COUNT(*)>1)
WHERE cd.funder='ABC' GROUP BY cd.contractID
```

**Edit:**
Here i found Solution DEMO http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69ee8/10

```
select td.trancheID,GROUP_CONCAT(td.contractID  SEPARATOR ';') as allcontract,SUM(s.totalPP) as totalPPtranche
from tranche_details td
left join
(
  SELECT cd.contractID,cd.funder,SUM(inv.purchasePrice) as totalPP FROM `contract_details` cd 
  INNER JOIN invoice_lineitem inv ON inv.contractID=cd.contractID
  WHERE cd.funder='ABC' GROUP BY cd.contractID
) s
  on td.contractID = s.contractID
  WHERE s.funder='ABC'
  GROUP BY (td.trancheID)
```

Comment: See aggregate functions in the manual.

Comment: @CY5 could you please show sample output what you are trying to achieve? Because I dont understand this line, 'get total purchase price of contracts based on contractID from invoice_lineItem and contract_Details and then get TotalPurchasePrice of all contract in the same tranche .'  Are you trying to get all result in same query? Please show sample output.

Comment: @kuttyraj i have updated my question